# Idiomatic way to reduce these two functions into one

Tags: go

I have these two functions which are very similar. They each parse an integer of a certain number base/bit length from a named query parameter. There are two functions to deal with unsigned/signed integers which requires calling either `strconv.ParseUint` or `strconv.ParseInt`.

What would be a neat idiomatic way to reduce these into a single function? I feel like using interfaces (and generics?) would be the way to go but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

func ParseQueryParamUnsigned(name string, base int, bits int, values *url.Values) (uint64, error) {

    param := (*values)[name]

    if len(param) < 1 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("missing parameter %s", name)
    }

    if len(param) > 1 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("duplicate parameter %s", name)
    }

    v, err := strconv.ParseUint(param[0], base, bits)

    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("bad value for '%s' (%s)", name, err.Error())
    }
    return v, nil
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

func ParseQueryParamSigned(name string, base int, bits int, values *url.Values) (int64, error) {

    param := (*values)[name]

    if len(param) < 1 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("missing parameter %s", name)
    }

    if len(param) > 1 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("duplicate parameter %s", name)
    }

    v, err := strconv.ParseInt(param[0], base, bits)

    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("bad value for '%s' (%s)", name, err.Error())
    }
    return v, nil
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but there's no reason to use pointers on `url.Values` or any other map except some special cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a generic parser like this:

```
func ParseQueryParam[T any](name string, values url.Values, parser func(string) (T,error)) (T, error) {

    param := values[name]

    if len(param) < 1 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("missing parameter %s", name)
    }

    if len(param) > 1 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("duplicate parameter %s", name)
    }

    v, err := parser(param[0])

    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("bad value for '%s' (%s)", name, err.Error())
    }
    return v, nil
}
```

And use it as:

```
value, err:=ParseQueryParam[int64]("param",values, func(s string) (int64,error) {
  return strconv.ParseInt(s,10,64)
})
```

Comment: I like that, I can make a couple of little wrappers but the bulk of it will all be in one function. Thanks.